# Can't find the new iOS Developer Program License Agreement I need to sign

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

A few weeks ago, I got this message when logging in itunesconnect.apple.com. I tried signing it back then, didn't find it and kind-of postponed the issue until later.

Well, later is now and I need to sign it to create a new app.

```
Review the iOS Developer Program License Agreement
The iOS Developer Program License Agreement has been updated. To create new apps and upload binaries to the App Store, the user with the Team Agent role must review and accept this agreement in Member Center.

Review the iOS Paid Applications Agreement
The iOS Paid Applications Agreement has been updated. To create new apps and upload binaries to the App Store, the user with the Legal role must review and accept this agreement in the Contracts, Tax, and Banking module.

To accept this agreement, the user with the Team Agent role must have already accepted the iOS Developer Program License Agreement in Member Center.
```

Unfortunately I can't find anywhere in the Member Center this new agreement to sign. I am the Team Agent

Has anybody encountered the same problem, or should I go ahead and call apple support?

Comment: oops, I just saw there is another question about the same topic from June 11.  I read June 2011 and figured it's kind of old. Sorry about that.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Well, I called apple support and they told me the usual story to clear the cache and use safari. Also, I sent them an email  with some screenshots of the steps I'm making. They replied they fixed the issue but to me it still doesn't work :(  I'll have to call them again tomorrow.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to `devprograms@apple.com` and posted on the forums. By the time I came back to iTunes Connect, the warning was removed I was able to create the App Record. Could be random. Best of luck.

Comment: I will submit one too then. Thanks

Answer (score 67):

That happened to me as well, but it was under Contracts, Tax, and Banking. You had to push a button that said request, or something like that, and check a box. Once you do that, it may take a few seconds to update, but you should be good to go.

Comment: I find iTunes Connect so strange, it's so unfriendly to users. It's unwise to just click around until it works, thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: iTunes Connect is a disaster.

Great answer @MZimmerman6! As they directed us AWAY from iTunes Connect - to a site where no agreement was presented - I never would have looked on iTunes Connect itself for the solution. It's now called  'Agreements, Tax and Banking'...

Comment: @shmim almost two years later I guess it is still applicable.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 I couldnt find any button of such kind. Is there any other means i can get rid of that warning? I need to submit my app and i couldnt because of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apple says we love the products they make. I don't like the developer part, it's a nightmare!

Answer (score 58):

First you have to Sign in to Member Center

https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#agreements

Check if you have accepted all the agreements.

Second:

Goto - https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/

or https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng

(Thanks for sharing Sikandar Khan)

You will see a warning sign once you login. It will say which module has to be accepted eg: (Agreements, Tax, and Banking module).. Click on the respective module icon.

It will request Amendments - On the right side of each amendment you will see a blue icon named "Request". Click on that, it wil show the agreement. Click on Agree.

Then it will move under "Master Agreements" to "Contract in Process":

You will have to Setup the required infos eg: Contact, Bank and Tax as per the agreement.

Once you have filled in the details, it will move to Contracts In Effect.

Comment: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/ gives a 404 error.

Comment: All apple docs should be this way, simple descriptions and clickable action text. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you RanjithKing. This solved my problem. 

Note: Second link has been changed to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng

Comment: Thank Sikandar Khan, have updated the link you shared.

Answer (score 16):

**First Step**

[image: Agreements, Tax and Banking]

**Second Step**

[image: Request button]

**Third Step**

[image: Review Agreement]

**Final Step**

[image: Done button]

Answer (score 8):

When you see this error:

[image]

You need to access the URL: http://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action via Safari.

(I didn't see the following on Chrome):

[image]

Comment: It's appearing on chrome. Thanks for the fix BTW

Comment: Was not showing up on Chrome, but appeared on Safari. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

We had a similar problem when our Team Agent tried accessing the Member Center from a PC, and couldn't find the agreement.  When we looked in Safari, it was there.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Tried Safari on a Mac. I don't know how to be more apple than this :)

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Worth a try. :-/

Comment: @AndreiStanescu - how did you resolve it. I am facing the same issue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't. I just waited and waited and in the end it appeared. I haven't faced this issue since then (2013).

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem today, in spite of all my research, impossible to publish following this update of conditions of use ... It is finally a phone call to the support Apple that solved the problem:

**There was a "bug" on the account following a transfer of the role "team agent"**. He solved the problem on his side in 2 minutes, so my advice => https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue,

Login to your iTunes account, go to the "**Agreements, Tax, and Banking**" section, You will see the Request Amendments, there will be request button, click it.
It will take you to the agreement screen, where you will be able to accept the agreement.

Doing this once, you will not be seeing the warnings in you iTunes account again.

Answer (score 3):

**2022 answer**

go to
https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#agreements and accept agreement

try again and it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

You just need to accept the latest agreement which will automatically popup at the top right corner.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, none of the above worked in Safari, untill........
I used Firefox!! 
Success

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the button until I used Safari (was using Brave).

Answer (score 0):

Login to Apple Developer Account [developer account](https://developer.apple.com/account)
on top of the screen you will see the information related to PLA. If you are logging in with the Admin of the app you will see option to Review the PLA and accept the same otherwise the information will show the Admin need to accept the PLA.

Answer (score 0):

I was first looking at "appstoreconnect.apple.com" but I needed to go to "https://developer.apple.com/". There I could accept it.